# Why my magento-1 website is showing as not secure?

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I have worked on website https://puppetkart.com/

I have bought ssl certificate from the hosting provider.

I have configured in admin panel also.[image]

But, stil website is showing as not secure at url

[image]

**Note :** Current domain is add-on-domain for another domain

Comment: Does your SSL Cert certified?

Comment: Check: http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-get-https-setting-up-ssl-on-your-website/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are obviously using a self-signed certificate with the subject puppetkart.depoto.com and issued by puppetkart.depoto.com. This certificate is not trusted by the browser since it is not issued by a trusted certificate authority. Therefore it is shown as insecure.

Comment: Thanks for response, Its issued by godaddy. What should i make changes to trust to the browser?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara: the certificate currently presented by your site is not issued by Godaddy but self-signed. This can also be seen from the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=puppetkart.com). My guess is that you maybe ordered the certificate but did not install it at your site. Once you have it properly installed rerun the SSLLabs test to see if it was properly installed.

Comment: I have understand what the problem is. Thanks for your reply. Accepted answer. Thanks alot